# Debugging MySQL: Too many connections

Tags: asp.net, mysql, mysql-connector

After we deployed the new version of our ASP.NET C# app with a MySQL DB we are having issues with the connections.

Yesterday I got the "Too many connections" error and I'm watching the open connections with 
`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` and they keep increasing during the day.

Is there a good way to figure out where our bug could be? Like checking the last query that a sleeping connection made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Connection pooling](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Connection_pool) usually solved this problem. In your case, connections seem to stay open much too long, which means that in some branches of your software, there's not definitive finally that closes the connection after it has been used. It's especially useful to diagnose problematic connection usage at a central point, because it can keep an eye on the number of open connections at any given time and maybe alert somebody to make a dump to analyze later.

You could also increase the number of connections allowed to your MySQL instance. The settings in your my.cnf is "max_connections".

Lastly, if you want you can try to decrease the "wait_timeout" or "interactive_timeout" properties of your instance. These settings regulate atomatic closing of connections after certain amounts of time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We do use the connection pooling that is enabled from MySQL by default. Changing the above mentioned values will be my last resort. I really assume that we are doing something wrong in the code, since we didn't have this issue before the release. What I'm looking for is a way to figure out where these open connections come from...

Comment: Adding a centralized connection pooling inside your application will create just that: A central point where you hand out or create connections, where you know exactly when a connection is created anew, at what time it was opened and (with a little bit of Reflection code) even who requested the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your app is closing connection to db properly....if your app not closing connections then you will get above error

Comment: Right. I understand that. The question is, how to find the place where a connection is not closed properly.